# Can i use gcov for kernel modules without recompiling the whole kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, gcov

I have ubuntu OS and i installed gcov in it.
I am able to use gcov for my c-program which is in user space and i am getting the desired results.
When i want to use gcov for my .ko files(kernel space) i am getting an error.
I googled and from the below mentioned link i found that i will have to recompile my whole kernel by enabling CONFIG_DEBUG_FS, CONFIG_GCOV_KERNEL, CONFIG_GCOV_FORMAT_AUTODETECT and CONFIG_GCOV_PROFILE_ALL.

http://techvolve.blogspot.in/2014/03/how-to-gcovlcov-for-linux-kernel-modules.html

Do i have any other way to integrate gcov for my kernel loadable modules without recompiling kernel?
If more information is required from my end please let me know. I will update it.
Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without support from the Linux kernel core you cannot collect coverage from a kernel module. So, if you current kernel has no such support, you have to recompile it.

---

*CONFIG_GCOV_PROFILE_ALL* isn't needed for coverage from the kernel module, however other configuration options are needed:

- CONFIG_GCOV_KERNEL - enables coverage counters in the kernel space,
- CONFIG_DEBUG_FS - enables debugfs filesystem, the only way for extract those counters into the user space,
- CONFIG_GCOV_FORMAT_AUTODETECT - describes the format of the collected coverage (you may chose configuration option which selects specific format instead of autodetecting).

Comment: any similar flag on ESXi ?

Comment: Do you have any idea whats the difference between CONFIG_ARCH_HAS_GCOV_PROFILE_ALL and CONFIG_GCOV_PROFILE_ALL ?

Comment: As far as I know, `ARCH_HAS` options about **ability** of the platform/architecture to support a particular functionality. If for some architecture has `CONFIG_ARCH_HAS_GCOV_PROFILE_ALL` set NO, then you cannot set `CONFIG_GCOV_PROFILE_ALL` to YES (and `make menuconfig` won't even show option `CONFIG_GCOV_PROFILE_ALL` to you).